# Find distribution of a bernoulli funtion of a unifrom random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I have a uniform random variable $\theta \in [-\pi,+\pi]$. I also have a bernoulli function of this random variable $G(\theta)$, defined as follows,

\begin{align} 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $ - x\leq \theta \leq x$};\\
         c & \text{OW}.\end{cases}
        \end{align}

Does anyone know what the distribution of $G(\theta)$ is?

Answer (score 1):

The distribution of $G(\theta)$ is given by
$$
\begin{align*}
\Pr[G(\theta)=1] &= \Pr[-x \leq \theta \leq x] \\
\Pr[G(\theta)=c] &= 1-\Pr[-x \leq \theta \leq x]
\end{align*}
$$
I hope that you can calculate $\Pr[-x \leq \theta \leq x]$ on your own.

Comment: is it $\frac{x}{\pi}$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I get as well.